# Dot product equivalent for complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, terminology

NB I'm not asking about the dot product for complex vectors, but rather something much simpler.

For vectors, a dot product is obtained as follows:

$$ \left<1,2\right> \cdot \left<3,4\right> = 11 $$

If I want the equivalent for complex numbers:

$$ 1+2i \left[ \textrm{some operation} \right] 3+4i = 11 $$

What do you call that operation? Thank you.

Comment: You could just as well define the dot product the exact same way for complex numbers: $(a+bi)\cdot(c+di)=ac+bd$

Comment: @Regret op is asking what, if anything, we call such an operation

Comment: @Kristoffer: Ah, I see. Unless it has a more common name, I think you could still call it "dot product".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $z_1=a+bi$ and $z_2=c+di$ we can show that

$$\Re(z_1\cdot \overline{z_2})=\langle a,b\rangle \cdot \langle c,d\rangle$$
where $\overline{z_2}$ is the complex conjugate of $z_2$ and $\Re$ is the real part of the expression.

Comment: Nice. It's trivial when you think about it, but I wasn't thinking. Indeed, the `dot()` function  in Matlab (Hermetian inner product?) already conjugates the first argument, so one can just take the real part of the product.